# Existence of a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a characteristic function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis and in section 5.11 he makes the next assertion:

> Put $g_n(t)=1$ if $D_n(t)\geq 0$, $g(t)=-1$ if $D_n(t)<0$. There exist $f_j\in C(T)$ such that $-1\leq f_j\leq 1$ and $f_j(t)\to g(t)$ for every $t$, as $j\to \infty$.

Here, $C(T)$ denotes the set of continuous functions on  the unit circle $T=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ and for $t\in T$, $D_n(t)=\sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ikt}$.

I know that by Lusin's theorem, we can find a sequence of continuous functions converging a.e. to $g$ with $|f_j|\leq 1$ for every function $f_j$ in the sequence, but I don't why he claims that we can find a sequence converging for every point. Could you help me to clarify this?

I think it suffices to show this for a characteristic function of a closed set since $g=\chi_F-\chi_{T\setminus F}$ where $F=D_n^{-1}([0,\infty))$ but I don't know how to prove this.
Thanks.

Comment: Your $g_n(t)$ is just a piecewise constant function that returns the sign of the $n$-th Dirichlet kernel. Do you know how to approximate a piecewise constant function by continuous functions? You don't need such machinery as Luzin's theorem. Recall that $$D_n(t)=\frac 1 2\frac{\sin(n+1/2)t}{\sin t/2}$$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, I know how to do that. I understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A standard way to obtain a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to $\chi_A$, for a closed set $A$: 
$$
f_j(x) = \max(0,1-j \operatorname{dist}(x,A))
$$
This works in every metric space. Indeed, 
$$x\notin A \iff \operatorname{dist}(x,A) > 0 \iff   1-j \operatorname{dist}(x,A) < 0 \text{ for large } j$$