# Sequence in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^{d})$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, cantor-set

i want to find a sequence $(f_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $f_i = \chi[0,1]^d$ for $i \rightarrow \infty$ in the $L^1$-Norm.

Any ideas for such a sequence or how to construct it ?

So it should be a continuous function with compact support ?

Comment: This might work (not sure if it works for $L^1$ convergence though): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/856773

Comment: good idea, thank you, still cant really construct it but it helps.

Comment: You mean $f_i$ converges to the characteristic function of $[0,1]^d$ in $L^1$ as $i\rightarrow\infty?$ (because that is not what's written in the question)

Comment: @projectilemotion pointwise convergence of bounded functions implies $L^1$ convergence by the Lebesgue dominating convergence theorem.

Comment: @Yanko Oh yes, you're right (though you also have to add that the measure space is finite and *uniform* boundedness for your statement to be true). You could just select the dominating function $g(x)=\max(0,1-\operatorname{dist}(x,[0,1]^d))$, which is integrable and satisfies $|f_i|\leq g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the discussion in the comments:

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856717/existence-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-converging-pointwise-to-a-charac/856773#856773), we let $f_i(x):=\max(0,1-i\operatorname{dist}(x,[0,1]^d))$, where $\operatorname{dist}(x,[0,1]^d)$ is the distance between $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and the set $[0,1]^d$ (you can verify that $f_i$ is continuous and has compact support). The idea behind choosing this sequence of functions is actually very intuitive: You fix all of the $f_i$'s to be $1$ on $[0,1]^d$ and you increase $i$ so that the region outside $[0,1]^d$ such that $f_i$ is nonzero shrinks to something arbitrarily small (think about the cases $d=1,2$ for simplicity). This works since $[0,1]^d\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is closed.

Clearly, $f_i\to \chi_{[0,1]^d}$ pointwise as $i\to \infty$. Now you need to show that $f_i\to \chi_{[0,1]^d}$ in the $L^1$-norm. As noted by @Yanko in the comments, you can do this using the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Let $g:=f_1$. Clearly one has that
$$|f_i(x)|\leq g(x)\, ,\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d,i\in \mathbb{N}\, ,$$
and $g$ is integrable (since it is bounded and nonzero only on a subset of finite measure). Hence $f_i\to \chi_{[0,1]^d}$ in the $L^1$-norm.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). If one does not like dominated convergence, one can also use that $f_i$ is supported on $[-1/i, 1+1/i]^d$ and coincides with $\chi_{[0,1]^d}$ on $[0,1]^d$ (both are $1$). Thus, we get $$ \Vert f_i - \chi_{[0,1]^d}\Vert_{L^1}=\int_{[-1,2]^d} \vert f_i -\chi_{[0,1]^d}\vert \leq \int_{[-1/i,1+1/i]^d\setminus [0,1]^d} 1 = (1+2/i)^d - 1 \rightarrow 0$$ for $i\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Clean answer, i solved it the same way. Showing continuity wasnt the problem. :)